# What is DirectX?

Tags: directx-11

I asked this question because since the start of this  generation of gaming , games are now being developed for on hardware that requires the support od DirectX11 and 12. So from my perspective, it looks like a driver software . Then I investigated and found out that games are now being written in DirectX11 code. So does this mean that it is a form of coding language?

**So could you please clarify what DirectX and what role it plays in game development?**